# Select a table column referenced by a cell parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I have in my excel table A1 cell - giving the name of the column table that I want to select.
e.g.: `A1 = Apr - Table2[Apr]`

I want a code that takes the value from **Cell A1** and selects accordingly the table column.
Something like as follows

Instead of:

```
Sub selection()

Range("Table2[Apr]").Select

End Sub
```

I would like to have something based on the following logic:

```
Sub selection()

Range("Table2[Cells(1,1).Select]").Select

End Sub
```

How should this be built in VBA?

Comment: Why would you want to Select? There is almost never a need to do so. In any event, just parse out the name of the column from A1, and use that to construct the appropriate string argument for the Range statement.  You want to wind up with `Range("Table2[Apr]").  Since your entry in `A1` appears to be a formula, you will need to access that property of the `Range("a1")` object to find the column name.

Comment: That should read, above **IF** your entry in A1 is a formula ... If not, you can get the string from either the default Value property or the Text property

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
range(range("A1")).select
```